# What does package-initialize do with package archives?

Tags: package

I'm reading through the definition of `package-initialize` to try and understand what goes on under the hood, and part of what it does is to read the package archive files. I see it comparing version numbers, but I don't fully understand what it's doing at a high level.

I'm looking at this method:

```
(defun package-read-archive-contents (archive)
  "Re-read archive contents for ARCHIVE.
If successful, set the variable `package-archive-contents'.
If the archive version is too new, signal an error."
  ;; Version 1 of 'archive-contents' is identical to our internal
  ;; representation.
  (let* ((contents-file (format "archives/%s/archive-contents" archive))
     (contents (package--read-archive-file contents-file)))
    (when contents
      (dolist (package contents)
    (package--add-to-archive-contents package archive)))))
```

I *think* it's being used to make sure that the packages we're loading also have their descriptors added to the package archives (e.g. `.emacs.d/elpa/melpa-stable/archive-contents` if they're not already in there. But I'm not clear on what these `archive-contents` files are used for, since running a command like `package-list-packages` communicates with the remote package archive.

I apologize if this question is a bit muddled, but I'm trying to push through the awkward early stage of learning emacs.

I should also probably mention that the reason I started investigating the internals of `package-initialize` was to figure out if there's some kind of lazy-loading that I could be doing, rather than loading everything as soon as emacs starts up.

Comment: Could you give the code of this function? The function may vary between versions.

Comment: Please ask a specific question about some part that you do not understand. Otherwise the question is too broad: at what level are you asking for a complete explanation of what it does? The code is of course the most complete explanation...

Answer (score 4):

`package-initialize` is supposed to find all the installed packages and *activate* them (depending on the optional argument) by executing their `<pkg>-autoloads.el` files.  Part of the complexity comes from the fact that it tries to make sure that it only activates a single version (the latest) of a given package (in case several versions of a package are installed).